# How to find row ID in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am creating multiple JQGrids in my code using single json. I am sending some delta value from server for refreshing the JQGrid. But how should I found the row_id of that row where this data is present to modify or delete it absed on a value present in that row?

Comment: please be more clear about what you are trying to do

Comment: It's better if you would insert some JavaScript code which shows how you create the grids. It's important that you include some test data too which you use as the input for the grids.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to "Find and Replace" certain rows to update them.

What you need to do is call `$('#myGrid').trigger('reloadGrid')` and have the grid update itself with the content returned from the method that populates the grid.

Answer (score 0):

One sees indirectly from your question that you don't full understand what is "rowid" and how it will be specified.

Every grid will be based with respect of HTML `<table>`. The main part with the data of the grid contains rows which will be represented by HTML `<tr>` elements. It's important to understand that jqGrid assign **always** `id` attribute for every row (every `<tr>` element). The value of the `id` attribute is the *rowid*. It's also important to understand that input data for the grid should not only contains the main data, but the ids of the rows too. *Only if you don't fill correctly the input data* jqGrid assign the values 1, 2, 3, ... as the rowids of the grid.

One more important thing which everyone have to know: the values of `id` attributes on one HTML page have to be unique. So if you fill *two grids on one HTML page with absolutely the same data* you can get the problem with id duplicates.

To reduce the problem with id duplicates I recommend you to use `idPrefix` option of jqGrid. For example if you would use `idPrefix: "g1_"` option in the first grid and `idPrefix: "g1_"` option in the second one then the ids 1, 2, 3, ... in *both* grids will be replaced by jqGrid to "g1_1", "g1_2", "g1_3", ... in the first grid and to "g2_1", "g2_2", "g2_3", ... in the second one. In other words the rowid will be constructed from the `idPrefix` and the id returned from the server (or generated by jqGrid).

The last recommendation: I would recommend you to include `id` values in the data which you use as the input for jqGrid.

Comment: my data is formatted with unique incrementing id values as shown in many examples from triand.. I am not always getting the right id returned in my onSelectRow when using scroll=1. It seems to be using an row-index relative to the current set of visible rows rather than the true row id.
Other aspects of my configuration:
rownumbers:true, rowNum:50, rowList:[50,100,250]